# UI responesive in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

I create an app that like dictionary app. When the user types in an Edittext, I call an AsyncTask to compute and update the result to the screen (I put the UI update code in onPostExecute() method ). However, when you type little fast, the eddittext become not responesive (a little latency). I think this promblem occurs because many AsyncTasks are running (each AsynTask for an input letter). So, I think I need to stop the first task before calling new task. Am I right? What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement the filter method in an async task. I call filter method on data when first letter has been written in editbox and save the result in an temporary array, then when another letter has been written, I call filter method on the temporary data which technically has less information than the original data. By doing this, the dimmension of data set decreases as you type in editbox. Also, you can use this method to store previous data set so when you press backspace, you don't have to call filter method again, you just go to previous saved temporary data set. For me, it works fine and I don't have to use async task because it is efficient

Comment: A good idea! But more specific, I get the data set using full text search. So the data set is in cursor. When I type a letter, I have to requery again and a new cursor returned. I can not filter on the old cursor because it does not provide full text search on cursor.

Comment: I think my problem maybe like this example: when I type 'a', I do a full text search and there are 3000 rows returned. I compute these rows and update to UI. But while this process has not finished, I type a letter 'n' (now 'an' is in edittext) and a new cursor with 200 rows returned. So I have to compute the cursor again. Maybe this causes a latency of the edittext. Could you give me a more specific solution (by code)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you another approach: use only one thread. The searching thread should wait for searching data > do search > and sleep until new data. E.g.:

```
private static class SearchThread extends Thread{

    private Object monitor = new Object();
    private String value;

    public void search(String value){
        this.value = value;
        synchronized (monitor){monitor.notify();}
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {System.out.println("Wait for search data."); synchronized (monitor){monitor.wait(); }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            System.out.println("Searching for " + value);
        }
    }
}
```